# How to convert current React Native project to ReactXP

Tags: react-native, reactxp

We have a developed `react native` project using `JavaScript`, now we decided to have it's website too. We found out that `Microsoft` introduced `ReactXP` and it is able to release website too. is it possible to convert current react native project to reactXP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You'll need to replace tags like `<View/>` with `<RX.View/>`, `<Text/>` with `<RX.Text/>`, etc.  Then, when compiling for the browser or native, ReactXP will internally exchange `<RX.View/>` etc. with the appropriate tag automatically depending on your current target (`<div/>` for the browser and `<View/>` for native).
But you don't have to exchange all tags with their `<RX.*` counterparts right away. Meaning you can still use a few `<div/>` etc. for the browser target and `<View/>` etc. for the native target. However, if you really only want one codebase and then cross-compile to any target, then you need to replace them all.
Styling is a bit different too: ReactXP doesn't have percentage values for width, height, etc.